# High Dimensional Data with time series

Tags: pandas

I am trying to make a pandas dataframe to hold my experimental data. The data is described below:

I have ~300 individuals participating in an experiment made of ~200 trials, where each trial has a number of experimentally controlled parameters (~10 parameters). For every trial and every individual I have a timeseries of some measurement, which is 30 timepoints long.

What is the best way to structure this data into a dataframe? I will need to be able to do things like get the experimental values for every individual at a certain time during all the trials with certain parameters, or get average values over certain times and trials for an indivudal, etc. Basically I will need to be able to slice this data in most conceivable ways.

Thanks!

EDIT: If you want to look at how I have my data at the moment, scroll down to the last 3 cells in this notebook: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UZG_S2fg4MzaED8cLwE-nKHG0SHqevUr/view?usp=sharing

The data variable has all the parameters for each trial, and the interp_traces variable is an array of the timeseries measurements for each timepoint, individual, and trial.

I'd like to put everything in one thing if possible. The multi-index looks promising.

Comment: You can add some data sample and expected output? Metadata are in lists ? What about data?

Comment: Your notebook is really interesting, but can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion need [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html).

**Sample**:

```
individuals = list('ABCD')
trials = list('ab')
par = list('xyz')

dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=5)
n = ['ind','trials','pars']
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([individuals, trials, par], names=n)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=mux, columns=dates)
```

---

```
print (df)
                2018-01-01 2018-01-02 2018-01-03 2018-01-04 2018-01-05
ind trials pars                                                       
A   a      x           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           y           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           z           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
    b      x           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           y           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           z           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
B   a      x           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           y           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           z           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
    b      x           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           y           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           z           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
C   a      x           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           y           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           z           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
    b      x           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           y           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           z           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
D   a      x           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           y           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           z           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
    b      x           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           y           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
           z           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```